# What is the cheapest/easiest way to pull data from SF into a google sheet?

Tags: lightning-apps, appexchange, google-apps

I'm looking for a simple way to push entries from a SF report to a google sheet, ideally in real time when the report updates, but a weekly timer or something along those lines would work too. I've looked on the AppExchange and I've seen apps like G-Connector or Edit Opportunities In Google Sheets, but I'm looking for a purely one-way connection, no edits in the google sheet affecting my SF data. Is there an app for this that I overlooked/didn't find, or a fairly easy way to do this myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You can use IFTTT to save new gmail attachments to Drive. If this recipe does not meet your needs, find a similar one that does: https://ifttt.com/applets/ESeruKXp-save-new-email-attachments-from-gmail-to-google-drive . Next you can use Kory108's February 2017 answer here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008n0zIAA to schedule your Salesforce Report to be sent as a .csv attachment to your email address on a daily or weekly basis.  If you do that and use IFTTT then it should be uploaded to Drive by IFTTT. Let me know if you have any questions.